# Creating infinite short lived threads

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have a javafx application and I am calling blocking methods in the FX thread by using

```
new Thread(() -> doWork(someParam)).start();
```

I want the user to be able to click a button that calls a method, but does not freeze the UI. I also want the number of clicks to equal the number of method calls.

This currently addresses my issue, however does this cause any issues regarding memory usage? I understand the thread will eventually die and the garbage collector will act on it, but is this bad practice?

Also when a new thread is created it gets assigned a new incremented Thread ID. 
Will there be an issue when the thread ID overflows?

Comment: It's just very slow to start threads. Otherwise you'll be fine, finished Threads and all the resources they occupied will be garbage collected when the Thread object and the resources become unreachable. In any case, use a threadpool: `ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newChachedThreadPool();` (or any of the other methods) - that way your code will be much faster.

Comment: You could use a pool of threads where the maximum number of threads in each pool is kept constant. When these threads join, a queue of jobs can be handed over to the pool manager, which will manage how many threads are live at a time.

Comment: No, there should be no issue with overflowing thread Id. even more so if you give your threads names. However, I suggest you use alternative approaches to actually creating `Thread` objects yourself. Executor services are more suitable for your needs. It also looks strange that you need number of threads equal to number of button presses. Why do you need that? This potentially duplicates work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threads are pretty expensive to create. You should use some kind of thread pool instead. The `Executors` class provides convenient ways to do this.

So for example you could do:

```
private final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

and then

```
exec.submit(() -> doWork(someParam));
```

There are also methods to create thread pools of a fixed size (`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n)`), and these methods are all overloaded so you can define how the threads are created when they are created. For example, if you wanted a cached thread pool, but wanted the threads to be daemon threads (so that they don't prevent application exit), you could do

```
private final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(runnable -> {
    Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    return t ;
});
```

Also note that at application shutdown, you should shut down your thread pool:

```
exec.shutdown();
```

As far as I am aware, overflowing the thread ID will not cause problems; the thread id is a `long`, so it will be difficult to reach overflow, and even if you do it will simply wrap to a large negative number. However it is generally better practice to use a thread pool as outlined here, which will make that question moot anyway.

Comment: I wrote the above as a comment on the question, because it doesn't answer the question "but is this bad practice? Will there be an issue when the thread ID overflows?"

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Good point. I added a couple of sentences, though tbh there are much better reasons to use a thread pool than worrying about overflowing a `long`.